# Building a queue in CouchDB

Tags: database, performance, couchdb, queue

This might sound like an obvious question, but I'm new to CouchDB, so I thought it was worthwhile asking in case there is something about CouchDB's structure that changes the situation that I didn't know about.  For reasons out of my control, I have to build a queue-like structure out of CouchDB.  For simplicity's sake, let's say I'm queueing IDs for jobs to be executed later.  Note that there will be no duplicates.

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to structure this is.  As I currently see it, I have a few options:

1. Store the queue items as entries in a `queue` database with the IDs as `_id`, and store the dequeued items in a similar `dequeued` database with the IDs as the `_id`.  Each record in each database wouldn't have any other information other than the (mandatory) `_id` and `_rev`.
2. Have a single queueing database, and that database will contain one record with `_id = 'queue'` and one record with `_id = 'dequeued'`.  Within each of the two records, there will be an arbitrary number of keys, each of which will be an ID for the jobs to be executed (or that were already executed).  The values associated in the database with the keys will be irrelevant, possibly just a Boolean.
3. Have a single queueing database, and within that database, have a single record called `queue`.  Within that record, have two keys: `queue` and `dequeued`.  Each of those keys will have as its associated value an arbitrary-length list of job execution IDs.

**1** is slightly less desirable because it requires two databases, and **2** strikes me as a poor choice because it requires loading the entire list of queued or dequeued items in order to read a list item or make any changes.  However, **3** is nice in that it allows for the whole list of IDs to be an ordered list rather than key/value pairs, which makes it easier to pick a random item from the list to be the next job to be executed, since I don't actually need to know any key names (since there are none).

I'm looking for whichever provides the best performance.  Any thoughts on this?

#### Update

For people reading this question in the future, I've built my CouchDB queuing module, `CouchQueue`, a work in progress.

You can get it `npm install couchqueue`.

Take a look (and please comment, pull request, etc.) [here](https://github.com/jdotjdot/CouchQueue) at Github.

Comment: What is the expected job throughput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one document per element in the queue, and keep one queue database.

I recommend a field to order the elements, for example `.created_at` with a timestamp in ISO 8601 format.

You can toggle an element's visibility with a `.visible` flag.

I recommend a map/reduce view, something like this

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.visible)
    emit(doc.created_at, doc)
}
```

Now you can query this view, either oldest-first, or newest-first (`?descending=true`). You can mark an element complete by updating it, setting `visible = false`.

I wrote a CouchDB queue, [CQS](https://github.com/iriscouch/cqs) which is identical to the Amazon SQS API. It is similar to what I describe, except there is a checked-out state messages can be, not visible in the queue for a timeout period. I have used CQS in production for about two years, with hundreds of millions of updates.

Comment: I ended up writing my own queuing system for CouchDB, which I will be open sourcing soon.  Unlike yours, mine is not identical to Amazon SQS, I built it just as a convenient queuing wrapper on top of `cradle`.

Comment: That queuing system, though still a work in progress, can be found [here](https://github.com/jdotjdot/couchQueue).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using separate documents for each queue entry, it will allow you to avoid conflicts.

If you just need an **queue** with the interface `push()`, `pop()`, `top()` for adding inserting an element and taking one then the solution may be very simple (if you want the **list** with `next()`, or accessing n-th element, it gets [more complicated](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/recipes.html#Ordering%20Lists)). For scheduling algorithm with linear order (like FIFO, FILO) you can implement `push()` as insertion of the new document:

```
{ type: "queue", inserted: CURRENT_TIME, ... }
```

`top()` as the map:

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type == "queue" && doc.inserted) {
    emit(doc.inserted, doc);
  }
}
```

and reduce as an aggregation (eg. max for FILO, min for FIFO).
For `pop()` you can ask view for the `top()` and then delete the document.
Map/reduce has to be deterministic, so if you want to choose the random element you can make the reduce dependent on the pseudo-random (chosen by the server) `_id`.

I expect two problems:

1. Mind the concurrency: two processes can ask for the same document with `top()`, first will delete the document as part of the `pop()`, and second will try to fetch the deleted document.
2. CouchDB never really deletes the document, only marks as deleted. Adding and deleting for each `push()`/`pop()` will grow the database. You will have to reuse the documents somehow. Perhaps you have some poll of the tasks, which are inserted and removed, or reordered in the queue. Then you can add `queued: true` to the task document, instead of separate documents with `type: "queue"`.